# How to open .aspx webpage in Internet Explorer using .bat (Domain)

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, batch-file, url, browser

Im only domain from a server, connections are using proxy server.

The question is how can I open a .aspx webpage, (ex:https://websample/sample/default.aspx)

When I try to insert it in my code, the webpage loaded but says "ERROR" on the page) BUT if I MANUALLY open that link in IE it loaded perfectly. I dont want to always click on a link simultaneously, So I want my .bat to open it for me multiple times, but it just won't load properly I only get errors.

This is my code

```
    @echo off
    start "1" "https://websample/sample/default.aspx"
    ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 300 > nul
    start "2" "https://websample/sample/default.aspx"
    ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 300 > nul
    exit
```

I guess what Im lacking is to recognize it as .aspx, by the way my webpage is using java & IBM View One to load images like "Fax Sorting" tasks.

Comment: These aren't URLs. URLs start with `http://` or `https://`. The only reason browsers accept addresses without a schema prefix is that they actually insert that prefix to make it easier for the user

Comment: yeah it has http// i just remove it here cause i cant put it multiple times when reputation is below 10

Answer (score 0):

I think you can should be able to directly use `iexplore.exe` with the url as argument:

With a 32 bit device:

```
start "1" "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "https://websample/sample/default.aspx"
```

With a 64-bit device:

```
start "2" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "https://websample/sample/default.aspx"
```

In my test this did not use the window title though.

Alternatively you could add a handler how to open `.aspx` files in general. That should apply to the command-line as well.

Comment: already tried that still error on loading, it display the page but and error like it cant find source or connection to server

Comment: @ChesterXianCruz But if it does show the page, it should be fine, or not?

Comment: it opens shows fine when i open it manually on IE, but on .bat it errors

Comment: error when using that command line, but manual open, its opens fine.

Comment: I understood that, but I am out of ideas... Have you tried placing an echo to check if the issued command is indeed totally correct. If so, have you tried running the command directly from command-line (and not from a batch-file)?